# how oozie timezone work, it does not pick the right timezone?

Tags: oozie, cloudera-cdh, oozie-coordinator

I have oozie job running on CDH cluster. I have the following coordinator

```
<coordinator-app name="name" frequency="0 */5 * * *" start="2020-03-05T16:00Z" end="2020-03-07T16:00Z" timezone="America/New_York" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4">
```

I submitted this job at `15:15` new york time and oozie started the first job right away and it was marked at `15:00` (new york time) and the next one is scheduled for `19:00`. I don't understand the time zone for oozie. Why it does not pick up the time zone I have specified ?

Answer (score 0):

You can over-ride the Timezone when submitting the oozie job on the terminal
-timezone EST -config coordinator.properties -run